# Solving The Figure Tab on MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, figure, matlab-uitable

I'm working with k-means and silhouette in MATLAB GUI. On my MATLAB GUI, there is some push buttons, let us call it 'k-means' and 'silhouette'.

This is the code for the k-means:

`[g c] = kmeans(data,k,'dist','SqEuclidean');`

`y = [data g];`

`t=uitable;`

`set(t,'Data',y) %this line will show the table in figure tab`

And this is the code for silhouette:

`[s,h]=silhouette(data,g,'SqEuclidean');`

It works perfectly fine. The silhouette function shows the graphic in figure tab. However, I want to create the table version, too, to see the silhouette value for each row. This is the code I've written:

`[s,h]=silhouette(data,g,'SqEuclidean');`

`z = [data s]`

`t = uitable;`

`set(t,'Data',z);`

It works but it looks like this:

[image: problem1]

I want the graphic and table shown in different figure tab.

I have tried add some thing like hold on, so my code was like this:

```
[s,h]=silhouette(data,g,'SqEuclidean');
  z = [data s]
  figure, hold on
  t = uitable;
  set(t,'Data',z);
```

And it is shown like this:

[image: problem2]

Almost works. But I want the FIGURE 3's background is clear, so there is only table in it.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want just by removing `hold on`.

If you'd rather have both the plot and the table in the same figure next to each other, you can adjust the position of the table like this:

```
set(t, 'Position', [left bottom width height])
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine. Thank you!